# How to use istat on AIX like stat on Linux distributions

Tags: find, aix, recursive, stat

In Linux, I use the following command to show this output:

```
 find /backup/$INSTANCE/tsm/* -exec echo '"{}" ' \; | xargs stat --printf "chown %U:%G '%n'\nchmod %a '%n'\n" >> /tmp/permissions.txt
```

the command returns output like this:

```
[filipe@filipe ~]$ cat /tmp/permissions.txt  
chown filipe:filipe '/backup/filipe/tsm/1347123200748.jpg' 
chmod 766 '/backup/filipe/tsm/1347123200748.jpg'
```

How can I make the same output using the istat command in AIX?

Simplifying, I need a recursive output that contains the chmod and chown command of the files read by istat.

Comment: is perl available?

Comment: (perl's installed by default, and is going to be much easier to work with than reversing the rwxr-xr-x-type permissions out of istat)

Answer (score 4):

Use `find`, but pass the filenames directly to a perl script that outputs the desired commands:

```
find /backup/"$INSTANCE"/tsm/* -exec /path/to/perl-script.pl {} +
```

Beware of filenames that contain single-quotes! I've modified the printed filename to quote any single-quotes.

## perl-script.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w
use strict;

for (@ARGV) {
  my @s = stat;
  next unless @s; # silently fail on to the next file
  my $filename = $_;
  $filename =~ s/'/'\\''/g;
  printf "chown %s:%s '%s'\nchmod %04o '%s'\n", $s[4], $s[5], $filename, ($s[2] & 07777), $filename;
}
```

If you prefer the textual user names and group names to the uids and gids, use the get* lookup functions:

```
...
  printf "chown %s:%s '%s'\nchmod %04o '%s'\n", (getpwuid($s[4]))[0], (getgrgid($s[5]))[0], $filename, ($s[2] & 07777), $filename;
...
```

Sample output:

```
chown 1000:1001 '/backup/myinstance/tsm/everyone-file'
chmod 0666 '/backup/myinstance/tsm/everyone-file'
chown 1000:1001 '/backup/myinstance/tsm/file'\''withquote'
chmod 0644 '/backup/myinstance/tsm/file'\''withquote'
chown 1000:1001 '/backup/myinstance/tsm/perl-script.pl'
chmod 0755 '/backup/myinstance/tsm/perl-script.pl'
chown 1000:1001 '/backup/myinstance/tsm/secure-file'
chmod 0600 '/backup/myinstance/tsm/secure-file'
chown 1000:1001 '/backup/myinstance/tsm/setuid-file'
chmod 4755 '/backup/myinstance/tsm/setuid-file'
chown 1000:1001 '/backup/myinstance/tsm/some-dir'
chmod 0755 '/backup/myinstance/tsm/some-dir'
```

Comment: using numbers on ID worked, but use names doesn't worked
$ cat /tmp/teste.txt
chown 57670:50011 '/backup/pddd767/tsm/Nodes'
chmod 0774 '/backup/pddd767/tsm/Nodes'

$ cat /tmp/teste.txt
chown pddd767:* '57670'
chmod 141533 ''
chown pddd767:* '57670'
chmod 141533 ''
chown pddd767:* '57670'


$ cat perl-script.pl
[... cut bcs ltd char] 
#printf "chown %s:%s '%s'\nchmod %04o '%s'\n", getpwuid($s[4]), getgrgid($s[5]), $filename, ($s[2] & 07777), $filename;
printf "chown %s:%s '%s'\nchmod %04o '%s'\n", getpwuid($s[4]), getgrgid($s[5]), $filename, ($s[2] & 07777), $filename;

Comment: my apologies, @FilipeTorres, my perl is apparently rusty! I wasn't pulling the appropriate element out of the get* functions; I've updated the code to do the right thing.

Comment: No problem @Jeff Schaller
i'm making a simple script to check and change all permiossion/owner of files.

you will help me a lot

Comment: Thanks, Stéphane; I had run the command on a separate directory, since I didn't actually have a /backup/.../ structure.

Comment: This path is irrelevant, because its change depends of some parameter of the script!

But i will try put your codes on the script, thanks everyone.