# Use small script inside another On AIX, or a solution in a single command

Tags: shell-script, shell, find, aix

I want put on a small script (perl-script.pl) inside another in order to use use it with a `find` command, like this:

```
#Saving the previous permission information for a possible recovery.
case "$STAND" in
        n|N|nao|no"")
        find /backup/"$INSTANCE"/tsm/* -exec /path/to/perl-script.pl {} + >> /tmp/permissions.txt
        chmod u+x /tmp/permissions.txt
    ;;
        s|S|y|Y|sim|yes)
        [... below code is similar of above]
    ;;
esac
```

## perl-script.pl

```
!/usr/bin/env perl -w
use strict;
for (@ARGV) {
  my @s = stat;
  next unless @s; # silently fail on to the next file
  my $filename = $_;
  $filename =~ s/'/'\\''/g;
  printf "chown %s:%s '%s'\nchmod %04o '%s'\n", (getpwuid($s[4]))[0], (getgrgid($s[5]))[0], $filename, ($s[2] & 07777), $filename;
}
```

In short, I would like to use this find command without having to import from another script -- or, how can I do this using a single command?

Comment: Might be useful to reference your [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477553/how-to-use-istat-on-aix-like-stat-on-linux-distributions), where the perl script originated (branched off of an `istat` suggestion), as a result of AIX not having a `stat` command that would tell you permissions, owner, and group in a more-direct way.

Comment: Since you already have a shell script that's running this `find` command, are you open to the idea of having a perl script do all the work? Invert the problem so that you have one script which does the find and the creation of the permissions.txt "script" as well as the existing shell script constructs?

Comment: Instead of using perl to print out shell commands, why don't you do the [`chmod`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chmod.html) directly in perl?

Comment: i don't know how do this!!

Comment: Glenn, my understanding (grain of salt included) is that this should result in some sort of recovery script; not one that is executed immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fully contained script to collect the ownership and permission attributes of a directory's contents for possible recovery, this script can be used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
sub wanted {
    my ( $mode, $uid, $gid ) = ( stat($_) )[ 2, 4, 5 ];
    printf "chown %s:%s '%s'\n", $uid, $gid, $File::Find::name;
    printf "chmod %04o '%s'\n", $mode & 07777, $File::Find::name;
    return;
}
my @dir = @ARGV ? @ARGV : '.'; # use current directory unless told
find( \&wanted, @dir );
1;
```

Name the script whatever you want. To run, pass the directory (or directories) you want sampled. If no argument is specified, the current working directory is used.